# Find next div of similar class. Not all sibling classes

Tags: jquery, find, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<button id="action">Next Div</button>
```

I want to add "active" class into next tab-pane div by clicking #action button. i.e. when I first click on `#action` button then my dom looks like -

```
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
```

and when I click the second time on `#action` button the dom looks -

```
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
```

How can I do that in jQuery?

Comment: Do you want to insert a `div` with some classes after the last element with a specific class (in your case `active`) oder do you want to add a class to the element following the last element with an `active` class. Can you please explain the first code block, it does not very similar to the following two, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```js
$('#action').click(function() {
  $('.tab-pane.active').next('div').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane active"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<div class="tab-pane"></div>
<button id="action">Next Div</button>
```

Comment: 1st: in my opinion even the question isn't clear yet (first code block unexplained), 2nd: please explain what your code is doing so unexperienced users can lewarn from the code plus its description.